# Converting curl command to python?

Tags: python, curl, command-line, python-requests, icinga2

I have this curl command, and I would like to transform it into a python request (including the query):

```
curl -u user:pwd123 -s -G --data-urlencode "q=GET services\nColumns: column1 column2 column3\nFilter: column1 ~~ stringtofilter\nFilter: column2 ~~ string2\nFilter: string3 ~~ string3tofilter" http://myendpoint.inet/api/query?
```

To convert it to python I can do this:

```
import requests

response = requests.get('http://myendpoint.inet/api/query', auth=('user', 'pwd123'))
```

But how can I include my query inside?

Comment: I use sometimes this site https://curl.trillworks.com/ , just when I feel too lazy to write it myself :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way to do that:

```
response = requests.get('http://myendpoint.inet/api/query', params = "q=GET services\nColumns: column1 column2 column3\nFilter: column1 ~~ stringtofilter\nFilter: column2 ~~ string2\nFilter: string3 ~~ string3tofilter", auth=("user", "pwd123"))
```

To see if the command is successful:
print (response)
It must return `<Response [200]>`

To see the response:

```
print (response.text)
```